# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Generator3D: Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "conv_resize_0.weight", "conv_resize_0.bias"

Tags: python-3.x, resolution, torch, state-dict

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Generator3D:
Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "conv_resize_0.weight", "conv_resize_0.bias", "bn_resize_0.weight", "bn_resize_0.bias", "bn_resize_0.running_mean", "bn_resize_0.running_var", "bn_resize_0.num_batches_tracked".
size mismatch for conv_minus_1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 3, 3, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 3, 3, 3, 3]).
size mismatch for conv_minus_1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_minus_1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_minus_1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_minus_1.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_minus_1.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for conv_res.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3, 3]).
size mismatch for conv_res.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for conv_res.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3, 3]).
size mismatch for conv_res.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.0.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.0.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.1.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
size mismatch for bn_res.1.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please look at [this page on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.